# Nodejs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined hashing password

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to hash password in my registration, at first when i dont have hash code, the code works but when I added the hashcode functionality, I received this error, please check the image below,

```
async function postUser(req, res, next){
    params = req.body;//post
    let validation_rules = {
        email: 'email|required',
        firstname: 'required',
        lastname: 'required',
        middlename: 'required',
        position: 'required',
        departmentid: 'required|integer',
        phonenumber: 'required',
        whatyoudo: 'required',
        password: 'required|confirmed|min:8',
    };

    let validation = new Validator(params, validation_rules);
    console.log("params", params);

    if(validation.passes())
    {
        try
        {   
            params.profilephotourl = "photourlsoon";
            let results = await user.newUser(params);

            res.status(200).json(results.rows);
        }catch(err){
            console.log("-----result data error-----\n", err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }else{
        res.status(400).json(validation.errors);
    }
}
```

//

```
exports.newUser = async function(data){
    try {
        bcrypt.hash(data.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        let sql = 'CALL "'+config.DBSchemaAAM+'"."sp_Users_insert"(\''+data.email+'\', \''+data.lastname+'\',\''+data.firstname+'\',\''+data.middlename+'\',\''+data.profilephotourl+'\', \''+data.position+'\', \''+data.whatyoudo+'\',\''+data.phonenumber+'\', '+data.departmentid+', \''+hash+'\')';
        console.log(sql);
        return pool.query(sql,)
        .then((res) => { return res;})
        .catch((err) => { return console.error('---Error executing query---\n', err.stack) });  
    });
    } catch(err) { return console.error(err); } 
}
```

error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens beca§use you are using callback when calling `bcrypt.hash` function, because of that your function `newUser` returns `undefined` that is expected.

Here how you can rewrite the function.

```
exports.newUser = async function(data) {
    try {
        return bcrypt.hash(data.password, saltRounds).then((hash) => {
          let sql = 'CALL "'+config.DBSchemaAAM+'"."sp_Users_insert"(\''+data.email+'\', \''+data.lastname+'\',\''+data.firstname+'\',\''+data.middlename+'\',\''+data.profilephotourl+'\', \''+data.position+'\', \''+data.whatyoudo+'\',\''+data.phonenumber+'\', '+data.departmentid+', \''+hash+'\')';
          console.log(sql);

          return pool.query(sql,)
                         .catch((err) => { return console.error('---Error executing query---\n', err.stack) });  
        });
    } catch(err) { return console.error(err); } 
}
```

Also unrelated to the question, but worth to mention, that you should not just put the data you receive from users into SQL query, you should use prepared statements otherwise you may be attacked with SQL Injections.